# Adding more monsters than provided tokens

Tags: gloomhaven

During Scenario 2 we ran into an issue where there were more of a certain monster type on the board than monster tokens of that type were available. So, we didn't have the correct pieces to put onto the board nor did we have space on the sleeved tracker to track their damage.

What happens during this instance?

Do we not put the monsters out since there are no more of that type available? Do we supplement the monsters with something else and still track them separately off the tracking sleeve? Do we do something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you run out of standees for a specific monster, you do not spawn any more.

From Page 19 of the rulebook:

> It is possible to run out of specific types of monster standees when
>   revealing a room. If this happens, **place only the standees that are
>   available**, starting with the monsters closest to the revealing
>   character.