# In Gloomhaven - do monsters spawn in the beginning of scenarios that have open doors/passageways to other tiles?

Tags: gloomhaven

I see the rules about how you spawn monsters in a new room when you "reveal" it by unlocking the door.  However, in some maps there are already open passageways between map tiles.  Does that mean the monsters on these tiles are all already "revealed" and spawn immediately from the beginning of the scenario?  Or do I still have to have a character walk on or look into the tile to activate and spawn the monsters?

I assumed the that they were revealed but noticed that in one of the scenarios I would run out of creature tiles for a specific type if they were all revealed at once in the large open multi-tile cave with no doors.

Comment: I don't think any of the scenarios should have more creatures on an initial spawn than what is available. Which scenario number were you seeing that one, and is it the first or second printing scenario book?

Comment: I forget the scenario number - but it's a 2nd edition printing.

Comment: so it was mission #43 Drake Nest for 2 players - it required 8 rending drakes but we only had 6 of them in the box.

Comment: As I just mentioned below, this map doesn't appear to contain any multi-tile rooms. Basing this off Page 57 of the first edition encounter book. Note that the "murky blackness" tile is a closed door. See Page 14 of the Gloomhaven Rulebook for an example of the "white murkiness" door, and the note about door art varying by environment type.

Comment: ah ok - didn't realize that the murkiness was a door.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, since rooms can be composed of multiple map tiles, you would spawn every monster in that multi-tile room.

Some overlay tiles, like Corridors, can combine multiple map tiles into a single room.

> Each scenario map is broken up into separate rooms by door overlay tiles. **A room may contain more than one map tile** if those tiles are connected by other overlay tiles. *(Page 13, Gloomhaven Rulebook)*

Thus, when following the scenario setup:

> Monsters in the **starting room** are placed at the beginning of a scenario. *(Page 13, Gloomhaven Rulebook)*

Or when revealing a new room when a door is opened:

> Immediately place overlay tiles, monsters, and money tokens as indicated in the scenario description for the **revealed room**. *(Page 14, Gloomhaven Rulebook)*

You do so no matter how many tiles that room is composed of.

It's OK to run out of a specific creature standee. You just [don't spawn any more of that creature](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/39477/adding-more-monsters-than-provided-tokens/39480#39480).

Comment: Ok.  So it seems like the only issue is that certain scenarios don't have enough creature stands to support the initial setup.  I'll see if I can dig up the scenario number.

Comment: Please do! I wouldn't mind taking a look. :) Good to verify that there aren't any other rules being missed.

Comment: so it was mission #43 Drake Nest for 2 players - it required 8 rending drakes but we only had 6 of them in the box.

Comment: This map doesn't appear to contain any multi-tile rooms. Basing this off Page 57 of the first edition encounter book. Note that the "murky blackness" tile is a closed door. See Page 14 of the Gloomhaven Rulebook for an example of the "white murkiness" door, and the note about door art varying by environment type.

Comment: Ah ok - didn't realize that the murkiness was a door.  It makes sense now.